# Handle Redis Cache error without site failure

Tags: azure, error-handling, out-of-memory, azure-redis-cache

Recently our Azure web app became unavailable due to our Redis Cache becoming full and our eviction policy being set to 'volatile-lru' while not setting an expiry date on our entries. We've since changed our eviction policy to 'allkeys-lru' to fix this.

My question is how could we have gracefully handled this error in our code or settings so that our entire application didn't fail? I'm unaware of any place in the Azure portal to specify this, nor in our application code. Searching online hasn't brought up anything relevant for the Azure redis cache.